# How to redirect to a page at a certain window width with Javascript/Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used media queries to make my website responsive. It works well when you shrink the window but when you make it larger without closing one element in breaks. 
So I am looking for a way to redirect to the 'main' page of my website when the user reached a breaking point while resizing the window. 
I tried this but it doesn't work :

```
function reload() {
  var width = $(window).width();
  if (width > 1000) {
    $('.page').hide();
  };
};
reload();
```

I also tried this but it doesn't work either :

```
function reload() {
  var w = $(window).width();
  if (w > 1000) {
    window.location.replace("WEBSITE");
    location.reload();
  };
};
reload();
```

this one reload without stopping but only if I manually reload the page once I've reach 1000px.

I also tried this : 
 window.addEventListener('resize', screen_resize);

```
 function screen_resize() {
        var h = parseInt(window.innerHeight);
        var w = parseInt(window.innerWidth);

        if (w > 1000) {
            window.location.replace("index.html");
            $('.page').hide();
            $('.content').hide();
            $('nav').hide();

        };
    };
```

But it keeps reloading if I resize after reaching the 1000px.

Thank you so much for your help :)

- A struggling young front-end developer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in function `reload` is static, i.e. it will execute only when you call it. If at the time of calling it, the window's width isn't more than 1000px, your function won't do anything.

You need to listen to the [`resize`](https://api.jquery.com/resize/) event instead:

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
  var w = $(this).width();

  if (w > 1000) {
    window.location.href = "WEBSITE";
  };
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help :) but I think your code kinda does the same thing as the last one I tried. The page keeps redirecting even after I reached the 1000px. I just want to it to redirected once when the window is 1000px or more.